# How to integrate autoconf into a kernel Makfile?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, autoconf

I have a kernel module project, and use autoconf to generate Makefile file inside the kernel module. And such autoconf usage breaks the kernel in tree source code build, because kernel Makefile doesn't support autoconf thus can't generate a configure file for the module. Is there a way to make kernel Makefile and autoconf compatible ? Thanks !

Comment: What for?? Have you ever thought why Linus never bothered to add support for autotools in the kernel?

Comment: Kernel is not a user space application. So, besides obvious nonsense, it can't be done without deep hacking.

Comment: Autoconf rules are sometimes useful when building external kernel modules for detecting kernel changes that cannot be detected at compile time, for example features backported by vendors (quite common in RHEL kernels, for example).

Comment: @IanAbbott Would you pls give me a link of RHEL module which utilizes autoconf ? I can't find it, thanks very much !

Comment: @Yifan I meant there are various kernel API changes that Red Hat have backported  that are not easy to detect by testing macros in kernel header files, but can be detected at configure time. So ./configure can define macros in a local header file according to the results of those tests. Examples of backported kernel API changes include the `gfp` parameter in `request_firmware_nowait` backported from 2.6.33 to 2.6.32, and the `try_wait_for_completion` and `completion_done` functions backported from 2.6.27 to 2.8.18. Those are just the ones that have bit me in the past. There may be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick I have used frequently in the past is to have two Makefiles - an automake generated one and a kernel one, and switch them around during "make".

Here is an example:

**Makefile.am**

```
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

## this is so that Automake includes the C compiling definitions, and
## includes the source files in the distribution.

## [@]kerneldir[@] is the kernel build directory.
## [@]kernelext[@] is the kernel module extension `ko`.
## [@]moduledir[@] is the module installation directory.
## [@]depmod[@] is the depmod program.

EXTRA_PROGRAMS = automake_dummy
automake_dummy_SOURCES = mymodule.c Makefile.kernel
generated_sources =

## there is no *just* object file support in automake.  This is close enough
module_DATA = mymodule.o
export_objs = mymodule.o

# where the kernel build is located
KERNEL_LOCATION=@kerneldir@

MYMODULE_TOP_SRCDIR = @abs_top_srcdir@
MYMODULE_TOP_BUILDDIR = @abs_top_builddir@
MYMODULE_BUILDDIR = @abs_builddir@

# some magic for using linux kernel settings
# when compiling module(s)
MYMODULE_EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB $(DEFS) -I$(MYMODULE_BUILDDIR) \
    -I$(MYMODULE_TOP_BUILDDIR) -I$(MYMODULE_TOP_SRCDIR)/include
export MYMODULE_EXTRA_CFLAGS KERNEL_LOCATION module_DATA export_objs

.PHONY: FORCE

$(automake_dummy_SOURCES): FORCE
    @test "$(srcdir)" == "." || test -e "$@" || ln -vs "$(srcdir)/$@" .

# Add FORCE in case the kernel has changed.
$(module_DATA): $(generated_sources) $(automake_dummy_SOURCES) FORCE
    mv Makefile Makefile.automake
    cp Makefile.kernel Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_LOCATION) SUBDIRS=$(MYMODULE_BUILDDIR) M=$(MYMODULE_BUILDDIR) modules
    mv Makefile.automake Makefile

install-moduleDATA: $(module_DATA)
    $(mkinstalldirs) $(DESTDIR)$(moduledir)
    @list='$(module_DATA:.o=.@kernelext@)'; for p in $$list; do \
      if test -f "$$p"; then d=; else d="$(srcdir)/"; fi; \
      f="`echo $$p | sed -e 's|^.*/||'`"; \
      echo " $(INSTALL_DATA) $$d$$p $(DESTDIR)$(moduledir)/$$f"; \
      $(INSTALL_DATA) $$d$$p $(DESTDIR)$(moduledir)/$$f; \
    done

uninstall-moduleDATA:
    @list='$(module_DATA:.o=.@kernelext@)'; for p in $$list; do \
      f="`echo $$p | sed -e 's|^.*/||'`"; \
      echo " rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(moduledir)/$$f"; \
      rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(moduledir)/$$f; \
    done

if SANDBOXED
else
install-data-local: install-moduleDATA
    -@depmod@ -a
endif

MOSTLYCLEANFILES = $(module_DATA) $(module_DATA:.o=.@kernelext@) \
    Modules.symvers Module.symvers Module.markers modules.order
CLEANFILES = $(module_DATA:.o=.mod.c) $(generated_sources)

clean-local:
    -rm -f .*.cmd .*.flags
    -rm -rf .tmp_versions
    -if test "$(srcdir)" != "."; then \
        for f in $(automake_dummy_SOURCES); do \
            if test "$$f" -ef "$(srcdir)/$$f"; then \
                rm -f "$$f"; \
            fi; \
        done; \
    fi

FORCE:
```

It uses some automake substitutions:

- `kerneldir` is the kernel build directory, e.g. /lib/modules/${version}/build
- `kernelext` is the module extension, which should be `ko`.
- `moduledir` is the module installation directory, e.g /lib/modules/${version}/extra
- `depmod` is the depmod program, e.g. set by `AC_PATH_PROG(depmod, depmod, /sbin/depmod, $PATH:/sbin)`

(You can replace all instances of `@kernelext@` in Makefile.am with `ko` if you want.)

The `automake_dummy_SOURCES`, `module_DATA`, `export_objs`, and `MYMODULE_EXTRA_CFLAGS` variables can be tweaked as necessary.

Note how the rule for target `$(module_DATA)` copies the Makefiles around before and after invoking the kernel's Makefile. The original (automake-generated) Makefile is renamed to Makefile.automake, and the other Makefile (Makefile.kernel) is copied in its place. When the sub-make completes without error, the Makefile.automake is moved back to Makefile. This doesn't work when the sub-make does not complete successfully, but that is dealt with by the other Makefile.

**Makefile.kernel**

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += $(MYMODULE_EXTRA_CFLAGS)

obj-m := $(module_DATA)
ifeq ($(VERSION).$(PATCHLEVEL), 2.4)
export-objs := $(export_objs)
endif

all mostlyclean clean maintainer-clean distclean:
    $(warning **************************************************)
    $(warning *** Makefile trick not undone, trying to recover *)
    $(warning **************************************************)
    mv Makefile.automake Makefile
    $(MAKE) $@

# The following is needed for 2.5 kernels and also let's the makefile work
# when things get screwed.
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(KERNEL_LOCATION)/Rules.make))
include $(KERNEL_LOCATION)/Rules.make
endif
```

This gets renamed to Makefile by the automake-generated Makefile rules during the kernel sub-make, and renamed back to Makefile.kernel afterwards.

The `all mostlyclean clean maintainer-clean distclean:` rule is for recovery when the previous make ended in an error, leaving the Makefile.kernel in place of Makefile. It moves the original automake-generated Makefile (now in Makefile.automake) back to Makefile and runs make again automatically.